# mongodb, how can I project or push root field on nested array using aggregate?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following example document with four nested arrays

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed6bd9596908c36f4200980"),
    "attr2" : "hello",
    "attr3" : 1234,
    "attr1" : {
        "firstArray" : [
            {
                "secondArray" : [
                    {
                        "secondAttr1" : "world",
                        "secondAttr2" : 456,
                        "secondAttr3" : [
                            {
                                "finalArray" : [
                                    {
                                        "finalAttr1" : "alex",
                                        "finalAttr2" : 9876
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

and this aggregate query that finds through nested arrays, unwinding and creating new root for each array processed, returning elements from "finalArray"

```
db.AssetTest.aggregate(
[
    {'$match':{'$and':[{'attr2': {'$eq':'hello'}}]}},
    {'$project': {'values': '$attr1.firstArray'}},
    {'$unwind':'$values'},
    {'$replaceRoot':{'newRoot':'$values'}},

    {'$project': {'values': {'$filter': {'input': '$secondArray','cond': {'$and':[{'$eq':['$$this.secondAttr1', 'world']}]}}}}},
    {'$unwind':'$values'},
    {'$replaceRoot':{'newRoot':'$values'}},

    {'$project': {'values': '$secondAttr3'}},
    {'$unwind':'$values'},
    {'$replaceRoot':{'newRoot':'$values'}},

    {'$project': {'values': {'$filter': {'input': '$finalArray','cond': {'$and':[{'$eq':['$$this.finalAttr1', 'alex']}]}}}}},
    {'$unwind':'$values'},
    {'$replaceRoot':{'newRoot':'$values'}}

    ]
)
```

the result for this aggregate is

```
{
    "finalAttr1" : "alex",
    "finalAttr2" : 9876
}
```

my question is, how can I project root field "attr2" through all aggregation stages so it will be on result array?

```
{
    "attr2"      : "hello",
    "finalAttr1" : "alex",
    "finalAttr2" : 9876
}
```

I'm new to mongo and I'm completely lost on this so any help will be very appreciated.

By the way I'm using mongo 3.4.15.

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case all you need is `$addFields` which got introduced in MongoDB version `3.4` :

I've cut down few stages & operators which doesn't seems to be useful, Check this latest aggregation pipeline :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      "$match": { "attr2": "hello" }
    },
    /** This stage adds new field to the place where you want */
    {
      $addFields: { "attr1.firstArray.secondArray.secondAttr3.finalArray.attr2": "$attr2" }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": "$attr1.firstArray"
    },
    {
      "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$attr1.firstArray" }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "secondArray": {
          "$filter": { "input": "$secondArray", "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.secondAttr1", "world" ] } }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": "$secondArray"
    },
    {
      "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$secondArray" }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": "$secondAttr3"
    },
    {
      "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$secondAttr3" }
    },
    {
      "$project": {
        "finalArray": { "$filter": { "input": "$finalArray", "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.finalAttr1", "alex" ] } } }
      }
    },
    {
      "$unwind": "$finalArray"
    },
    {
      "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$finalArray"}
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y7ge3LAT4iv)

**Ref :** [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html#addfields-aggregation)

**Note :**

1. You don't need to use `$and` on single conditions (Refer your 1st stage).
2. You don't need to multiple `$project` stages in the middle for conversion (Refer your 2nd stage).

Comment: Thanks whoami, works perfect. And thanks for your notes, I need to fight with mongo a little more ;)